# Why am I getting an error stating that "mail() expects parameter 1 to be string"?

Tags: php, email, csv

So basically, I am trying to create a bulk email application.

I am allowing the upload of a CSV file with a few emails, and once I click send they will all be processed and sent.

I parse the CSV file into an array, and I am using a `foreach` loop to handle each email address and send it.

For example, this is called after the `csv` array has been populated:

```
foreach($csv as $email_address)
{
   $sendHeaders = "headers here";
   $sendSubject = "subject here";
   $sendText = "long email text here";

   mail($email_address,$sendSubject,$sendText,$sendHeaders);
}
```

Although, I seem to get the error of:

```
Warning: mail() expects parameter 1 to be string
```

It states that the error is on line 54, which is the line where my `mail()` function is being called.

Does anyone have any idea to why this is happening?

---

EDIT:

Here is a var_dump of my array if anyone is after it:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => email1@foo.com
            [1] => email2@foo.com
            [2] => email3@foo.com
        )

)
```

Comment: What does your csv array ($csv) look like?

Comment: what's the csv array look like?

Comment: I think you may need to add the csv data before you'll get meaningful answers. Also, what's the output of `echo $email_address;`, called immediately before `mail`?

Comment: The error message is quite self-explained, it means your `$email_address` is **not** a `string`.

Comment: Yeah, figured I'd need to add that, so I made a quick edit straight after I posted the question.

Comment: well yup its a multidimensional array, hope your not on a shared host :-)

Comment: @Dagon - .....Haha, I am. Is that a problem?

Comment: @fizzix: will the array continue to look like that? (all email addresses will be added after email3@foo? If so you need to do foreach $csv[0] as $email_address)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your loop to:

```
foreach($csv as $email_addresses) {
    foreach($email_addresses as $email_address) {
        $sendHeaders = "headers here";
        $sendSubject = "subject here";
        $sendText = "long email text here";

        mail($email_address,$sendSubject,$sendText,$sendHeaders);
    }
}
```

In fact the problem was that your `$csv` is a two-level array, hence its elements are **not** strings, you must iterate on its elements to get the actual email addresses.

Also, if `$sendHeaders` and/or `$sendSubject` are always the same, you could move them before the loop so you do not set them each time.

Lastly, as @Dagon suggested, if `$csv` always has only one element, you could simply do:

```
foreach($csv[0] as $email_address) {
    $sendHeaders = "headers here";
    $sendSubject = "subject here";
    $sendText = "long email text here";

    mail($email_address,$sendSubject,$sendText,$sendHeaders);
}
```

Comment: Ahhhh! Great, now I understand. Worked perfectly in the end. And yes, both those variables will be the same each time, therefore I will put them outside the loop. Thanks!

Comment: @fizzix you're welcome :) if my answer helped you feel free to upvote and/or accept it!

Comment: Upvoted already, although I have to wait another 5 minutes to accept haha.

Comment: In this specific case, yes, but who knows whether `$csv` is ever going to have more elements? I preferred a more general solution, but I will integrate your suggestion :)

Comment: i prefer the solution with the least overhead.:-)

Comment: And what if then you have to rewrite it all for a simple change in `$csv` array? Also, let's say it, the overhead in this case would be negligible.